# How do I get elements using getCriteria from a specific date?

Tags: plugin-development, elementcriteriamodel

I'm trying to get elements in a section created on a specific date. How do I do that?

This is what I've been trying with:

```
$criteria               = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
$criteria->section  = 'sectionHandle';
$criteria->postDate     = '2014-11-04';
```

Comment: Can anyone suggest an update to the accepted answer that works in Craft 4? I'm getting errors to the effect of "Class "modules\modulename\services\ElementType" not found'.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
$criteria->section  = 'sectionHandle';
$criteria->postDate = array('and', '> 2014-11-03 23:59:59', '< 2014-11-05 00:00:00');
$results = $criteria->find();
```

Comment: This works great Brad. Is there any way I can make it just by the date and not include the time? I tried yii-syntax with **postDate = ['IN', '2014-11-04']** but that got me a "Fatal error: Call to a member function getTimestamp() on a non-object in /craft/app/helpers/DbHelper.php on line 597". Any ideas?

Comment: Nothing I can think of...

Comment: Is there another way you would recommend me fetching elements from a section posted at a specific date using Craft build in API functions?

Comment: Not without directly querying the database.