# Get entries by date range from plugin

Tags: plugin-development, search, elementcriteriamodel, postdate

Im trying to figure out how to get Entries by date range, say I would like to get all Entries from one week back, or I would like to get all Entries from a specific month.

I find some Twig examples, but haven't successfully been able to translate them to php for use in my plugin.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, found an answer that made it a bit clearer:
[How do I get elements using getCriteria from a specific date?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/8739/how-do-i-get-elements-using-getcriteria-from-a-specific-date/8747#8747)

Basically you can do this:

```
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
$criteria->postDate = '>'. date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-4 weeks"));
$result = $criteria->find();
```

To get Entries form a month back.